# C++ remove an element from vector of objects based on index or prompt

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have these two boolean methods that I need to implement that rely on a vector of Question objects:

```
/* Remove Question either by index or prompt */
bool Quiz::removeQuestion(int index) {
    // TODO: check how to remove questions by index
    Questions.remove[index];
}

// TODO: check how to remove questions by string prompt
bool Quiz::removeQuestion(std::string prompt) {

}
```

I have looked up ways to use erase() and remove() but I cannot figure out exactly how to approach this. Both seem to need a range of indexes but I just need to remove a single element (Question object) when given a specific index or when given a specific prompt. I have seen other solutions on here but they only work with vectors of integers while my issue is related to a vector of objects. Any solutions?